# After a reboot is there a way to restore prior windows like terminals and gnotes to what they were before a reboot?

Tags: reboot, restore

I have a dual boot setup (GNU/Linux-Debian-Buster & Windows 10).

Sometimes I have to shutdown GNU/Linux, thus closing all of my many open windows with work in progress, to be able to temporarily use Windows 10.

Later when I return to GNU/Linux I've lost what I was working on.  I have to scratch my head to try and remember my open terminals, gnotes, and the like.

In GNU/Linux is there some way to save and then restore prior windows like terminals and gnotes to what they were before a shutdown or reboot?

In other words, is there someway to essentially do what FireFox does, in that it saves the open tabs from before.

Answer (score 1):

If your system support it, you can hibernate debian into his swap partition. Then restart MS_Win10 (that could also be hibernated in his own pagefile.sys file). Then, again, restart in debian et voilà...

Suppose you share files between the two OS, you should take care you can't be here and there at the "same" time. See "Back to the future" for more informations about [Time Space Continuum](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W3LwlSlo5cw). You cannot use ubiquity without compromising your integrity.